# How to put the search box in the bar

Tags: html, css

i want to put the "text type input" in the bar which the icons are in , how can i do it??

here is the whole code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body{
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    #mostTop{
      height: 35px;
      background: url("img/_TopCampain1404303550.jpg");
    }
    #bar2{
      height: 35px;
      width: 100%;
      border-bottom : solid 1px #F2F2F2;

      float: left;
    }

    #bar2 > #AccountsBox{
      float: left;
      border-left :solid 1px #F2F2F2;
      width: 280px;
      height: 35px;
      margin-left: 100px;
    }
    #bar2 > #AccountsBox > .items{
      float: left;
    }
    #bar2 > #AccountsBox > .items{
      float: left;
      width: 45px;
      height: 35px;
      border-right:solid 1px #F2F2F2;
    }
    #bar2 > #AccountsBox > #twitter{
        background: url("img/twitter.png")no-repeat;
        background-size: 45px 35px;
      }
    #bar2 > #AccountsBox > #facebook {
       background: url("img/facebook.png")no-repeat;
      background-size: 45px 35px;
    }
    #bar2 > #AccountsBox > #googleplus{
      background: url("img/googleplus.png")no-repeat;
      background-size: 45px 35px;
    }
    #bar2 > #AccountsBox > #instagram {
      background: url("img/insta.png")no-repeat;
      background-size: 45px 35px;
    }
    #bar2 > #AccountsBox > #telegram{
      background: url("img/telegram.png")no-repeat;
      background-size: 45px 35px;
    }
    #bar2 > #AccountsBox > #aparat {
      background: url("img/aparat.png")no-repeat;
      background-size: 45px 35px;
    }

    #bar2 > #AccountsBox > #twitter:hover{
      transition: 0.25s;
      background: url("img/twitterHover.bmp")no-repeat;
      background-size: 45px 35px;
      cursor:pointer;
    }
    #bar2 > #AccountsBox > #facebook:hover {
      transition: 0.25s;
      background: url("img/facebookHover.bmp")no-repeat;
      background-size: 45px 35px;
      cursor:pointer;
    }
    #bar2 > #AccountsBox > #googleplus:hover{
      transition: 0.25s;
      background: url("img/googleplusHover.bmp")no-repeat;
      background-size: 45px 35px;
      cursor:pointer;
    }
    #bar2 > #AccountsBox > #instagram:hover {
      transition: 0.25s;
      background: url("img/instaHover.bmp")no-repeat;
      background-size: 45px 35px;
      cursor:pointer;
    }
    #bar2 > #AccountsBox > #telegram:hover{
      transition: 0.25s;
      background: url("img/telegramHover.bmp")no-repeat;
      background-size: 45px 35px;
      cursor:pointer;
    }
    #bar2 > #AccountsBox > #aparat:hover{
      transition: 0.25s;
      background: url("img/aparatHover.bmp")no-repeat;
      background-size: 45px 35px;
      cursor:pointer;
    }

    #bar2 > #search > #searchBox{
      height: 20px;
      margin-top: 0%;


    }
    #bar2 > #search > #magnifier{
      height: 35px;
      width: 45px;
      border-right: solid 1px #F2F2F2;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="mostTop"> </div>
  <div id="bar2">
    <div id="AccountsBox">
      <div id="twitter" class="items"></div>
      <div id="facebook" class="items"></div>
      <div id="googleplus" class="items"></div>
      <div id="instagram" class="items"></div>
      <div id="telegram" class="items"></div>
      <div id="aparat" class="items"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="search">
      <input type="text" placeholder="search..." id="searchBox">
      <input type="image" src="img/search.png" id="magnifier">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i just want to put the search box in the bar(the bar's name in the code is bar2).
i tried some normal ways but it seems there is something i dont know!!

Comment: What exactly is it that you are trying to do here? Running your code it looked like your search input was in the header with the icons (or where the icons would be if I had the image assets). Are you trying to align it differently? Or position the search somewhere else?

Comment: @ldtcoop I think the main issue is that the icons won't show up.. the path given a) doesn't have a trailing slash or b) point to specified domain, so that could be part of the issue...

Comment: @RachelGallen I'm assuming that they're his local files

Comment: @ldtcoop yes, I realise that, but they may not be referenced correctly is what I'm saying. Or the file could have been written and moved ..

Answer (score 0):

you may be looking to do the following

```css
input[type="text"]{
      height: 30px;
      font-size: 20px;
      background-image: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-512.png");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 20px 20px;
      background-position-y: 50%;
      background-position-x: 5px;
      padding: 5px 5px 5px 40px;
    }
```

```html
<form id="search" action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" placeholder="search..." id="searchBox">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```